# Why isn't jasmine running any of my specs?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jasmine

I added `gem 'jasmine', '~> 2.0.0'` in my `Gemfile` (`group :development, :test`) and ran the generator `rails g jasmine:install`.

I have **one simple spec**:

```
# spec/javascripts/truth_spec.js 
describe("Truth", function() {
  it("herps the derps", function() {
    expect(true).toEqual(true);
  });
});
```

When I run `rake jasmine` I get presumably normal output:

```
your server is running here: http://localhost:8888/
your tests are here:         /Users/jared/git/givegab/spec/javascripts
your source files are here:  /Users/jared/git/givegab

>> Thin web server (v1.5.1 codename Straight Razor)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:8888, CTRL+C to stop
```

I open `http://localhost:8888/` in my browser and I get **a blank grey screen**.  My JS console is empty, no errors, and when I trace execution using a debugger **I can step through** `boot.js` and `jasmine.js`.  No errors are raised.

I can set a debugger breakpoint in `truth_spec.js` and it never gets hit.

This is my first time using jasmine, so **please assume I am missing something obvious**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My colleague has found the root problem.  To our great embarrassment, we were overwriting `window.onload`.  I can't think of any way jasmine (or S.O.) could have identified such a foolish mistake.  Thanks for taking the time to help us troubleshoot this.

The gem author [ragaskar](https://github.com/ragaskar) [helped us troubleshoot this](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine-gem/issues/192), and gave us some good tips.

Comment: `(window.onload === null)` for me. Still cannot hit breakpoints inside of `it(...)`.

Answer (score 3):

If jasmine is setup correctly, then opening `http://localhost:8888/jasmine` in your browser should run all of your specs.

You can also run specific specs with:

`http://localhost:8888/jasmine?spec=herps the derps`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a file in `config/initializers/` called `jasminerice.rb`, with the following contents in it, if you want to use the interactive web version:

```
# Use this file to set configuration options for Jasminerice, all of these are initialized to their respective defaults,
# but you can change them here.
if defined?(Jasminerice) == 'constant'
  Jasminerice.setup do |config|
    # Tell Jasminerice to automatically mount itself in your application. If set to false, you must manually mount the
    # engine in order to use Jasminerice.
    #config.mount = true

    # If automatically mounting Jasminerice, specify the location that it should be mounted at.  Defaults to /jasmine, so
    # you could access your tests at http://YOUR_SERVER_URL/jasmine
    #config.mount_at = '/jasmine'

    # Specify a path where your fixutures can be found. Defaults to 'spec/javascripts/fixtures'
    #config.fixture_path = 'spec/javascripts/fixtures'
  end
end
```

Be sure to restart your rails server afterward. This initializer sets up the routes at runtime for the jasmine web view, so if you run `rake routes | grep jasmine`, you should see the following:

`jasminerice          /jasmine                                                                                                                  Jasminerice::Engine
           GET /spec/:spec_id/fixtures/*filename(.:format) jasminerice/spec#fixtures
spec_index GET /spec(.:format)                             jasminerice/spec#index
           GET /fixtures/*filename(.:format)               jasminerice/spec#fixtures
           GET /(:suite)(.:format)                         jasminerice/spec#index`

Comment: My project does not use the jasminerice gem.  We have used the [jasmine](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine-gem) gem on its own for as long as I've been on the project.  We're just trying to upgrade jasmine to 2.0.  Do we really need the jasminerice gem?

Comment: Ah, here we've always used both from day 1. I almost forgot they're different gems. Yes, if you want easy rails integration and a route that is hosted by your rails server, then you'll need to use `jasminerice`.